# Full clone in a Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to do some analysis on my Git repository for each build using a custom bash script. This requires that Jenkins checks out the full Git repository and do not perform a sparse checkout. How can I do this? I am using a pipeline script. I can do another checkout during the build but then I need to inject Jenkins credentials (which is not what I want).

My Jenkins console log always shows that a sparse checkout has been done:

```
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 1d94145c47cf93a9561b59ed3ba37b936ce15d38
```

Comment: i suspect that you're using a declarative pipeline, and that the relevant checkout happens during the "Declarative: Checkout SCM" stage (you might paste a minimal Jenkinsfile if you can). i suspect you can't change the way *that* checkout happens, though you can skip that checkout and do your own with custom options (sure, you would need to configure credentials, but that's also part of the Pipeline Syntax generator).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add shell script steps to fetch the branches and checkout the branch you like after the sparse checkout? Something like:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master or git checkout <your_desired_branch>
```

Comment: the worst thing you can do is shell script for everything.

Comment: the best thing you can do is a shell script for everything.